# Can I use a nonstick or stainless steel pan to bake a cake in a microwave

Tags: cake

Can I use a nonstick pan or a stainless steel pan to bake a cake in a microwave?

Comment: You may want to clarify what you mean by "nonstick pan".  That could mean literally anything.

Comment: Bake a cake in the microwave? Metal in a microwave? . ... . . ... .

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can cook in microwave safe cups or basically anything that is microwave safe. If you don't have anything big enough to cook a cake do you maybe have a large based jug?

Answer (score 1):

NO. Do not use metal in the microwave.  It will spark due to the charged particles that start going crazy in the metal. General rule just like mom and dad said ... Don't do it.

Get a ceramic bake pan.

And remember microwave safe plastic does not mean food safe. Cooking in plastic is bad. Microwave safe means the plastic wont melt.... not that the plastic wont transfer chemicals into food.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But not all ceramics are microwave safe, so read the labels or choose glass. Also I wouldn't call heating batter in a microwave "baking", but that's probably just my definition.

Comment: No, microwave safe means they're actually safe. See for example http://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/microwaving-food-in-plastic-dangerous-or-not which specifically mentions for migration of chemicals.